# Gallop Search Time Complexity?

Tags: time-complexity

[Gallop search](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_range.html#SearchPolicy) is for searching for an element in a sorted list. You start taking an element at index 0, then at index 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc. until you overshoot your target, then you search again in the range that you just found.

What's the time complexity of this? It seems to me to be some sort of logarithmic time complexity, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(Please see my EDIT below)**

lets look at the worst-case behaviour. search continues from 0, 1, 2, 4, 8....
lets say n is 2^k for some k >= 0. in the worst-case we might end up searching until 2^k and realise we overshot the target. Now we know that target can be in 2^(k - 1) and 2^k. The number of elements in that range are 2^(k - 1) (think a second.). The number of elements that we have examined so far is O(k) which is O(logn). The following recurrence summarises it.

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + O(logn) 
     = T(n/4) + c1log(n/2) + c2logn ((all logs are base 2.))
     .
     .
     .
     .
     = O((logn)^2)
```

So the worst-case complexity of this algorithm is quadratic of logn. It maybe not the tightest bound but it is a good upper bound.

**EDIT:** I'm mistaken. I have taken the definition of gallop search given here literally without following the link. The link says, once we overshoot, we do binary search in the previous interval. It takes log(n) time to overshoot the target and log(n) time to do binary search in the sorted interval. This makes it O(log(n)) algorithm. Thanks to [Sumudu Fernando](https://stackoverflow.com/users/163824/sumudu-fernando) for pointing it out in the comments. I appreciate it.

Comment: It seems to me to be a little faster, shouldn't it? Because you're *not* doing `log(n)` comparisons *for each iteration*; you're doing fewer and fewer as time goes on... I'm not sure what that is, though...

Comment: yes. you are right! first iteration takes log(n), second iteration takes log(n/2) ...... summing it gives tighter bound. Agreed! I gave upper bound... I'm not sure if summing tightly changes complexity asymptotically.

Comment: Oh... hm... that means we have `log(n) + log(n) - log(2) + log(n) - log(3) ...` and yeah, yours is a pretty nice bound; thanks!

Comment: The link says that it switches to binary search after the initial "galloping".

The overall complexity is just O(log(n)) (it even says that in the link!)

Comment: Isn't the time complexity independent of N (which could even be infinite)? For the first stage which finds the correct interval, it is O(log(k)), k = search key index. Same for the second stage. The total time complexity is 2*O(log(k). As we usually ignore constants in time complexities, the total is O(log(k)). Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search